# JAVA: Why my host and post are return null in other class

Tags: java, get, null, set

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class connectFenetre {

  private String host ;
  private Integer port ;
  public connectFenetre(){
   }

  public void run()
  { 

     String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's the port? and host?

    String[] token = input.split(":");
     if(token.length != 2){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "need host and port!");
     }


     this.host = token[0];

    this.port = Integer.parseInt(token[1]);
    System.out.println(getPort());
    System.out.println(getHost());
     CommBase c = new CommBase();
     c.start();
     FenetrePrincipale fenetre = new FenetrePrincipale(c);
     c.setPropertyChangeListener(fenetre);
 }

 public String getHost(){
    return host;
 }

 public Integer getPort(){
        return port;

  }
 }
```

Why are my port and host returning null in other class?

In the other class I declared

```
connectFenetre c = new connectFenetre();
println("c.getPort()");
println("c.getHost()");
Output: NULL NULL
```

Comment: And where you execute the run method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `c.Run()` after creating `c` for the code that sets the host and port to be executed. Try this:

```
connectFenetre c = new connectFenetre();
c.run();
println("c.getPort()");
println("c.getHost()");
```

You may also want to initialize the host and port fields to some default value in the `connectFenetre` constructor. This will avoid `NULL` values even if `run()` is never executed.